# "Top of Page" link in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css

Using php in a webpage and struggled with anchoring to the top, so I'm using a line of javascript to accomplish what I want. The code is:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<a href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>");
// -->
</script>
```

Only problem is, I want to take the code and add a:

```
class="bmenu"
```

line to it so it will be formatted the same as other links (color, font, etc.). I know nothing of javascript, so this is probably a simple thing, but would be a really helpful workaround for those who need to link to the top of a page, but have limitations as to which method they can use.

Thanks in advance!

Here's what the code looks like for those curious.

I have a .php file titled bmenu.php that contains a bottom menu that is added to every page. It contains

```
|&emsp;
<a href="index.php" class="bmenu">Home</a>
&emsp;|&emsp;
<a href="about_us.php" class="bmenu">About Us</a>
&emsp;|&emsp;
<a href="find_us.php" class="bmenu">Find Us</a>
&emsp;|&emsp;
<a href="contact_us.php" class="bmenu">Contact Us</a>
&emsp;|&emsp;
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<a class=\"bmenu\" href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>");
// -->
</script>
&emsp;|
```

and then in each file that I want this menu I add

```
<?php include 'PHP/bmenu.php'; ?>
```

This saves typing and enables me to make a single edit to the menu rather than editing every page that I want that menu on every time I want to change it.

Comment: Uh, just `<a href="#">TOP</a>` would do that, this looks really wonky!

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. That's what I was using until I realized the way I was using .php to build pages, all were linking back to the top of the home page, hence why I needed a workaround. My menu itself that contains the "link to top" code is part of a small .php file that is copied onto each page-- must be why they all link to the top of the home page I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.write("<a class=\"bmenu\" href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>");
```

Comment: Wow! Solved in under a minute! I feel rather stupid. Thanks so much @simon ! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Try Some animation effect-**

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body id="top">
      .........
      .........
      <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>
</body>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoa, this looks cool. I'm too much of a novice to see how to fully implement tho. This appears to be something that wouldn't work with my site currently. Using

    <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>

in my .php built site links me back to the top of my home page rather than my current page, the the need for the JavaScript to grab the current page. If I were to switch that line with

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    document.write("<a class=\"bmenu\" href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>");
    // -->
    </script>

would it still work?

Comment: Sorry,@WebDevRon, that should have been in code `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> <!-- document.write("<a class=\"bmenu\" href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>"); // --> </script>`

Comment: <a href="#top">Back To Top</a> will always works on every page. Just add an ID named "top" to body of every page such as-
<body id="top">

Comment: Then something really messed up is going on with mine, cuz every page has a top id yet every page's link to top is linking back to the top of the home page. My thought is that my link to top is in a very small .php file that just contains a bottom menu that is added to every page.

Comment: Then without showing the code, it is hard to solve the problem. Cause there is no error in my code.

Comment: **Just replace this**

`document.write("<a class=\"bmenu\" href= \"" + document.location + "#top\" >Top of Page</a>");`

**With**

`document.write("<a class='#'>Top of Page</a>");`

Comment: Just tried it. Doing so leaves "Top of Page" without any link at all.